# Turn rate limit (throttle) down for a specific origin in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, rest, http-headers, rate-limiting, throttling

I have a Laravel-made API running in a server and an Angular application running in another server. My Angular app loads a huge JSON file (with more than 500 lines) and tries to insert each line in a database through the api. A request is sent for each line, so I get an 409 error (too many requests).

I know this is a matter of security, so I don't want to remove the throttle from my middlewareGroup array in Kernel.php. I'd like to know, however, if there's any chance I can turn this rate limit down for a specific origin address (http://www.myangularapp.com/ only, for example)? So I can send these various requests while keeping the rate limit for other origin addresses.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes you can. Just extend the existing ThrottleRequests middleware and add an exception list or higher rate for selected routes. Then replace the old throttle middleware with your custom one.

Comment: That's it! I wish I could make this comment the answer of this question.